# Calculating Date difference with NaT values

Tags: python

I have two features of datetime type, few records of each column have NaT values. These NaT are meaningful and I can fill it up with 0.
What I want to do is to find the difference between the two dates to create a new feature "Time Spent". Because of NaT, my code is throwing error, which makes sense as I am trying to subtract NaT values. I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do it in Python. Thanks in advance

### Example :

```
DateTime_Min        DateTime_Max         Process
2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:30.  A
2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:20.  B
NaT.                NaT.                  C
2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:30.  D

What I want:
---

DateTime_Min        DateTime_Max         Process. Time_Spent(seconds)
2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:30.  A.      30
2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:20.  B.      20
NaT.                NaT.                  C.      0
2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:30.  D.      30
```

### **Code**

```
#calculating time spent on each process in seconds 
def calculate_seconds(df):
    if (df['DateTime_Max'] == 0 | df['DateTime_Min'] == 0):
        df['Time_Spent']=0
    else:
        df['Time_Spent']=(df['DateTime_Max'] - df['DateTime_Min'])/np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `fillna`:

```
df.DateTime_Min = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime_Min)
df.DateTime_Max = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime_Max)
df["Time_Spent"] = (df.DateTime_Max - df.DateTime_Min).fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
```

The result is:

```
         DateTime_Min        DateTime_Max Process Time_Spent
0 2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:30       A   00:00:30
1 2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:20       B   00:00:20
2                 NaT                 NaT       C   00:00:00
3 2020-01-01 11:30:00 2020-01-01 11:30:30       D   00:00:30
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?